# Calculate $\nabla\times(f\cdot\nabla g)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How does one calculate the following formula
$$\nabla\times(f\cdot\nabla g)？$$
I tried using the indenity
$$
\nabla \times(fg)=\nabla f \times g+f \nabla \times g,
$$
but it seems wrong for the first formula. Can anyone help with this? I would appreciate it.

Comment: If you don't want to use identities because you don't trust them to be valid (which is an entirely legitimate reason), you can just use the definitions.

Comment: @wasser You should at least indicate the domains/co-domains... Is it $f,g:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: Does "$f\cdot \nabla g$" indicate not a dot product but rather scalar multiplication, i.e.,  $(f\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_1}, f\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_2}, \ldots, f\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_n})$ ? If not, then the expression doesn't make sense.